# clickonce signing trustworthy

Tags: vsto, clickonce, signing, visual-studio-2015

I have created a word add-in and I want to deploy it with clickonce.
I tried it on another session on my computer but I can't install it, it says that the certificate is not approved but I signed it with a certificate I created with makecert.

How can I make it work on any computer without having to add the certificate to the trusted list on each computer I want to install my add-in on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot, because that's what certificates are for. You can either buy a certificate from some authority, or you'll have to ask your users to install your self-signed certificate as trusted root.

Comment: I installed self-signed certificate under 3 places (Personal, Trusted Root & Trusted Publishers) on test system. But getting certificate not signed error on test computer. Working fine in developer machine. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try and configure the clickonce [trust prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308453.aspx).